# Sharepoint webpart postback issue

Tags: c#, sharepoint, postback, web-parts

I created a treeview webpart, and if you click a node, it modifies a SPList, and clears and recreates the treeview.

So when I click a node, the page gets refreshed, then the treeview function occurs and edits the list and recreates the treeview. THEN the problem is if I were to refresh the page by hitting F5, the same thing happens again i.e. the List gets modified again even though i didn't click a node.

I suspect something like the treeview node select change event was activated again.

As well this happens when I hit refresh:

[image]

Is it somehow resending the tree click flag or something? How can I clear it when refreshing so it doesn't try to resend it?

Comment: Did you try reading the error message before just hitting one of the buttons?  It's specifically warning you that it's about to do exactly what you're asking about.

Comment: Is there a way to clear it when the refresh button is pressed, so it doesn't try to resend the request?

Comment: There are hacks around it, yes, but in general it's a browser/user issue.  You don't want to be refreshing the page when you just performed an action unless you want that action to be performed again.

Comment: Are there ways to detect is the page has been refreshed with the user clicking on "Retry" on the pop up box?

Comment: Not really, at least not any good ways.  That's the wrong avenue for approaching this problem anyway.

Comment: What if I use a flag variable, so like when I click a node, I set a variable to true, then on the tree click function I check if that variable is true, then if it is It does some code and sets the variable to false. Then if the page gets refreshed, the variable will be false still and it wont modify the SPList. Could this work?

Comment: If there are no circumstances in which they should ever be performing that action twice, then yes, that's an acceptable way to do it.  You'll just need to have some sort of data structure (`Dictionary` comes to mind) to have a boolean value that corresponds to each node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common approaches for preventing actions performed on postback from being called repeatedly by user's refreshing the page:

1. In whatever code that they are running do some sort of check to see if they have already done what they are about to do.  Sometimes this is easy (i.e. they clicked to delete an item, but I see it's already deleted) and sometimes it's just not possible or practical.
2. After performing the postback that you don't want to be repeated do a `Response.Redirect` (to either another page, or even just the same page).  By doing this when they hit refresh their 'last action' won't be the pastback, it will be the result of the redirect.  Of course, if they start using their history to go 'back' they could easily end up redoing whatever action you had done before.  This course of action isn't stopping them from intentionally (or maliciously) duplicating the action, it's just allowing them to hit 'refresh' without accidentally duplicating the action.  Also note that this comes with a cost.  You will need perform another back and forth with the client, and you'll need to re-generate the entire page (this will likely have a performance cost, and potentially be difficult to implement as well, depending on the specifics).